# Почему после добавления виртуального ISO образа не запускается установщик windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualbox, установка, виртуальная-машина

Пытаюсь установить windows 7 на virtualBox 6.0. Никогда раньше не работал с виртуальными машинами, поэтому возникла проблема. Вроде бы делаю все по инструкции, выбираю ISO образ, он даже добавляется в меню Носители, вот скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда запускаю виртуальную машину, ничего не происходит. Если я правильно понял, то после добавления ISO должна запуститься установка ОС? У меня все такой же черный экран, какой был до добавления ISO.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите все правильно настроить. Спасибо.

Comment: Поставьте его первым в очереди перед vdi, выберите пункт Primary Master (это в англ. версии), а диск вторым

Comment: @Spartacus Нет возможности так сделать. Есть вторичный мастер, первичный слейв и вторичный слейв

Comment: Тогда не знаю, сто лет уже им не пользуюсь, привык уже к VMware Workstation, он намного стабилен и для меня удобен